# Making a script to change regedit values in all folders and subfolders

Tags: for-loop, cmd, regedit, dword

Im sure as hell not in any way an experienced coder, so bear with me with these questions.

Im trying to change a `LoadBehavior REG_DWORD 0x00000002(2)` to a value `0x00000003(3)` in several folders incl their subfolders. I want the script to run through each of the folders and subfolders and change the value to 3 if they find the REG_DWORD type. 
I dont want it to add a REG_DWORD if there isnt any.

Edit:
After help from JosefZ I have edited my code below:

Its probably an easy fix for you fellow coders :) Looking forward to hearing from you

### My whole code listed below:

```
@echo off
echo Start af Registry p† remote pc
set /p input="Maskinens wrk-nummer:"
sc \\%input% config remoteregistry start= auto
sc \\%input% start remoteregistry

reg query \\%input%\hku /v LoadBehavior /s | find /I "HKEY_USERS\"

for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
    reg query \\%input%\hku /v LoadBehavior /s 2^>NUL ^| find /I "HKEY_USERS\"
  ') do (

         rem next command is merely displayed for debugging purposes
    echo REG ADD \\%input%\%%G /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
         rem remove `ECHO` from above command no sooner than debugged

)

Choice /M "Vil du gerne ogs† †bne Registry?"

If Errorlevel 2 Goto No

If Errorlevel 1 Goto Yes

Goto End

:No

Echo Programmet lukker

Goto End

:Yes

Echo Registry †bner

start regedit.exe


:End

timeout 2
```

### Results running the code above:

```
Start af Registry på remote pc
Maskinens wrk-nummer:wrk0022423
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Der kører allerede en udgave af tjenesten.

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\AdHocReportingExcelClientLib.AdHocReportingExcelClientAddIn.1
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\PowerPivotExcelClientAddIn.NativeEntry.1
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\AccessAddin.DC
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Add-On-Products.ResourceFinder
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\ColleagueImport.ColleagueImportAddin
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\TelemetryAddin.Connect
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\OneNote.PowerPointAddinTakeNotesService
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\OneNote.WordAddinTakeNotesService
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\AdHocReportingExcelClientLib.AdHocReportingExcelClientAddIn.1 /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\PowerPivotExcelClientAddIn.NativeEntry.1 /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\AccessAddin.DC /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Add-On-Products.ResourceFinder /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\ColleagueImport.ColleagueImportAddin /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\TelemetryAddin.Connect /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\OneNote.PowerPointAddinTakeNotesService /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\DYMO.LabelWriterAddIn /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
REG ADD \\wrk0022423\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\OneNote.WordAddinTakeNotesService /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
Vil du gerne også åbne Registry? [Y,N]?
```

Comment: I don't understand `\%input%\ ` meaning; please [edit] your question to explain it. However, `reg query …` should set `errorlevel` variable to `0`/`1` if present/missing queried value, respectively.

Comment: `reg query hku /v LoadBehavior /s | find /I "HKEY_USERS\"` should  show all subkeys where `LoadBehavior` value occurs. Parse above command using [`FOR /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Comment: The \%input%\ is because I've made a command to ask for user input, which is the remote machine Im trying to change the registry in. 

My whole code is below. Its partly in Danish, so dont get confused :)

Comment: **Please** use [edit] instead of commenting (as I suggested already); code becomes unreadable if placed  in a comment. Moreover, [StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) are not chat-like ones; please take the 2-minute [tour].

Comment: `ERROR: Invalid key name` is here because of trailing backslash in `reg query \\%input%\hku\\`.

Comment: I removed the \ but then i got an Invalid Syntax error. I then tried to remove the '2^>NUL ^' and it moved on it seems

Comment: Yes note the difference in presence/absence of `^` caret in stand-alone `reg query …` versus `for /F` loop against the same command: `… 2>NUL | find /I "HKEY_USERS\"` versus `… 2^>NUL ^| find /I "HKEY_USERS\"`.

Comment: Ahh yeah you are right. With the information the code gives me so far, can I edit all of the "LoadBehavior" files found or do I need the /F loop?

Comment: Please go back to the `for /F …` code snippet from my answer. You could change all `LoadBehavior` in _every_ sub-key  found as advised already, or you could narrow changes to any sub-choice e.g. using `find` or `findstr`.

Comment: I have edited my question with the newest code and it seems to run smooth now. It finds the REG_DWORD files and it runs the REG ADD command but it doesnt change the values in the regedit. If I try and open cmd manually and paste one of the REG ADD lines it changes just fine. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Please read explaining `rem` comments within the code snippet. Operational command is merely displayed  using `ECHO` for debugging purposes: remove the word `ECHO` as soon as debugged. Now I can see that you should use double quotes as follows: `REG ADD "\\%input%\%%~G" /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f`

Comment: Ohh stupid me.. Ofc. Thanks a lot mate. It actually works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show all subkeys where a value occurs (used `temp` value name instead of `LoadBehavior` merely for demostration):

```
==> reg query \\%input%\hku /v temp /s | find /I "HKEY_USERS\"
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Environment
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3900305277-3673560937-2769375459-163256\Environment
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Environment
```

Use next [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) instead of `reg add …` in your code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
    reg query \\%input%\hku /v LoadBehavior /s 2^>NUL ^| find /I "HKEY_USERS\"
  ') do (

         rem next command is merely displayed for debugging purposes
    echo REG ADD \\%input%\%%G /v LoadBehavior /d "3" /t REG_DWORD /f
         rem remove `ECHO` from above command no sooner than debugged

)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time on this. I just tried to implement it into my code, but a little bit unsure as of how it should be done. I tried to swap my REG ADD out with for /F but nothing happens when I run the script then?

Comment: Add `reg query \\%input%\hku /v LoadBehavior  /s | find /I "HKEY_USERS\"` somewhere before/above the `for /F`. Is output non-empty? @MathiasBorggaardKanstrup

Comment: I did as you said and its loading for a few minutes but at the end I get: 
The specified path was not found.

Comment: Well the first time I added everything in your first answer, but I tried only adding the reg query \\%input%\hku /v temp /s | find /I "HKEY_USERS\" above for /f and it still loads as before but there is no error output now

Comment: @MathiasBorggaardKanstrup try _both_ `reg query \\%input%\hku /v temp /s` and `reg query \\%input%\hku /v LoadBehavior /s` (omit `| find /I "HKEY_USERS\"`) to see real effect. Please then add result(s) to your question including possible error message(s).

Comment: I have edited the code as you suggested and it seems like they find the LoadBehavior files now. However the temp line seems to give an error. Am I right? The question is now, how do I alter/edit them?

Comment: @MathiasBorggaardKanstrup If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.